# Laravel socialite with multi provider

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, twitter, laravel-socialite

I'm using laravel 5.4 and also use socialite package to handle register/login from social network accounts.
corrently I have code below and users can register/login via facebook but I also want twitter and google system as well.

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        try {
            $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->fields([
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'gender'
        ])->scopes(['first_name', 'last_name'])->user();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect()->route('user.index');
        }

        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

        Auth::login($authUser, true);

        return redirect()->route('jobseeker.profile');
    }

    /**
     * Return user if exists; create and return if doesn't
     *
     * @param $facebookUser
     * @return User
     */
    private function findOrCreateUser($facebookUser)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('fb_id', $facebookUser->id)->first();

        if ($authUser){
            return $authUser;
        }
        return User::create([
            'fb_id' => $facebookUser->id,
            'first_name' => $facebookUser->user['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $facebookUser->user['last_name'],
            'username' => $facebookUser->user['last_name'],
            'avatar' => $facebookUser->avatar,
            'email'  => $facebookUser->email,
            'gender' => $facebookUser->user['gender'],
        ]);

    }
```

The issue I'm facing is if I use only one provider like Facebook which I am now everything is fine but if I add second one register/login system with socialite wont work.

I read some articles and saw they used like

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
```

but honestly I didn't get it how it makes difference between providers and recognize them.

So I need help to get those two social accounts works on my project as well as facebook does.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I know its a tutorial for 5.3 but you can take the same principles and apply it to your situation. [Social Login with Multiple Providers](http://backendtime.com/laravel-social-login-multiple-providers/). You need to pass a string to the driver to let it know which provider you wish to use. Its also shows a efficient way to set up your tables, search for the migration section. Hope this helps.

> The authenticate method makes use of the driver method of Socialite, which takes a string representing the social provider we want to use. It’s important to note that this method expects a value matching a supported provider. So, if we want to authenticate with facebook we should pass the string facebook; for Google we pass google and so on.

Comment: that link you given not working

Comment: @EmtiazZahid this post is 4 years old. Might be better looking at [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite](Laravel Docs) instead, probably best to move away from Laravel 5.4 first and EOL of 5.4 was July 24, 2017. Loads of tutorials on google.

Comment: "Google tutorials" isn't helping, of course. If anyone still wants to access rbaskam's link, you can use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170512060954/http://backendtime.com/laravel-social-login-multiple-providers/).

Comment: Sorry was my poor formatting [Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/socialite)